# MongoDB Query Dynamic keys

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Need to find quoteIds where having different values and keys should start with 1 or 2 or 3. Could you please help.

```
{
 "quoteId": 1,
 "screening": {
    "101": 1,
    "201": 1,
    "301": 1,
    "100": 1,
    "200": 1,
    "300": 1,
    "111": 1,
    "211": 1,
    "311": 1
  }
}

{
 "quoteId": 2,
 "screening": {
    "101": 1,
    "201": 1,
    "301": 1,
    "100": 1,
    "200": 1,
    "300": 1,
    "111": 1,
    "211": 2,
    "311": 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. `$set` - Create `screenings` array field, by converting object (key-value pair) to multiple documents (via `$objectToArray`) and fulfill the regex with starting of 1 or 2 or 3 in `$filter`.
2. `$match` - Filter documents that `screenings` is not an empty array.
3. `$unset` - Remove `screenings` field.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      screenings: {
        $filter: {
          input: {
            "$objectToArray": "$screening"
          },
          cond: {
            "$regexMatch": {
              input: "$$this.k",
              regex: "^(1|2|3)"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      screenings: {
        $ne: []
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "screenings"
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Xgtgp_sl2y0)

Comment: this keeps the documents that have at least one key that starts with 1 or 2 or 3, if you want to filter the array you can use something like [this](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=625ad87f8b39bcf74dae2738) almost same query without the unset and convert back to object. In case he needs something this.